# Is it possible to edit metadata of images in a Mac OS Photos library?

Tags: metadata, apple-aperture, macintosh

I recently started using the Photos app built into the Apple Mac OS. I cannot find a way to edit the images' metadata except for Title, Description, and/or Keyword. And it seems that I can only do so via the Info window.

[image: Info window]

**Is there a way for me to edit or create any additional EXIF metadata fields for images in a Photos library?**

I'd be willing to do so outside the Photos app such as via a command line interface or a third-party tool.

Also note this related, yet-unanswered question: [Is there a way to batch-edit metadata in the Mac OS Photos app?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/91460/67211)

Comment: What specifically do you want to edit? It's hard to think of a reason to edit the reported aperture or shutter speed, for example.

Comment: @Caleb I'm not interested in editing those items, but I'd like access to the other standard fields, like those that are part of the XMP standard.

Comment: also asked here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365200/how-to-edit-icloud-photos-library-exif-metadata-on-the-mac

Answer (score 3):

Within Photos, the only EXIF or IPTC data you can edit directly is what you see in the info window.

There are some batch EXIF editing tools available for macOS on the Mac App Store:

[Photos EXIF Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photos-exif-editor/id1202851767?ls=1&mt=12)

[EXIF Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-editor/id477514607?mt=12)

(I've not used either of these, so have no idea how well they work.)